# Levels of parameter sets for a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

What I want is to get-help to output the below for my cmdlet

```
SYNTAX
Get-Somehting -A <Object> [-Package <Object>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Somehting -A <Object> [-Names <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Somehting -B <Object> [-Package <Object>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Somehting -B <Object> [-Names <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

The following

```
Function Get-Somehting{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName='A')]
        [System.Object]$A,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName='B')]
        [System.Object]$B,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName='package')]
        [System.Object]$Package,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
        ParameterSetName='Names')]
        [String[]]$Names)
    Process{
    }
 }
```

gives me

```
SYNTAX
Get-Somehting -A <Object> [-Package <Object>] [-Names <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Somehting -B <Object> [-Package <Object>] [-Names <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: can you please fix formatting?

Comment: Your expected syntax output describes an unusable command. If you were to invoke `Get-Somehting -A something`, PowerShell wouldn't be able to tell if you were trying to invoke this parameter set: `Get-Somehting -A <Object> [-Package <Object>]`, or this one: `Get-Somehting -A <Object> [-Names <string[]>]`, and you'd receive an `AmbiguousParameterSet` exception...

Comment: Your example does not match what you say it gives you. It should output 4 options like `Get-Something -A <Object> [<CommonParameters>]`, one each for `-A`, `-B`, `-Package`, and `-Names` since you have 4 sets, and each set has 1 parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most annoying and coolest features is parameter set names. What's cool is you can properly define your input for the 'path' you want your code to take, and rather check what 'path' was input instead of checking all the different input parameters. You want to be very careful when defining them, however, as pwsh REALLY wants to end up with just one invoked 'path', so you have to properly define your expected paths:

```
Function Get-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'AName')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'APackage')]
        [System.Object]$A,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'BName')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'BPackage')]
        [System.Object]$B,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'AName')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'BName')]
        [System.Object]$Package,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'APackage')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'BPackage')]
        [String[]]$Names)
    Process {
        $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
    }
}
```

It's kind of messy, but it also makes sense as in your case you want to always have an "a or b" path and with that always define either names or packages, so you end up with 4 possible 'paths'.